# Changing cursor: pointer to custom cursor in CSS

Tags: css

I have a really big project where I need to change all the `cursor: pointer` to a custom pointer

Here's how the normal pointer looks:

[image]

One way to do it is to create a class like the following in CSS and apply it to every element in html where the custom pointer is supposed to appear:

```
.custom-pointer {
    cursor: url("../img/custom-pointer-cursor.png"), auto;
}
```

The problem though is that that pointer is supposed to appear in a 100+ places in the project and I was wondering if there is a way to just override `cursor: pointer` with my custom pointer with only a couple of lines of code in css.

I have looked on the web but have not found anything similar to what I want to do.

Comment: Do u want that image on the cursor?

Comment: What about using tag selectors?? like "button, input[type='submit']"

Comment: @jo12345678 please check below answer, thank you !

Comment: Any halfway decent IDE should have functionality to do a search & replace over all project files … so replacing `cursor: pointer` with `cursor: url(…), auto;` should not be that big of a deal to begin with. (And if the use of white space isn’t that consistent across the project, a regular expression search should be able to handle that as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically we use `pointer` on anchors and buttons, if there is something else where you need custom cursor, I think you can use following code:

```css
a,button{
 cursor: url("../img/custom-pointer-cursor.png"), auto;
}
```